# Dojo Datagrid - Get the row number

Tags: dojo, dojox.grid

I am trying to retrieve the line number in dojo data grid. rowIndex function would not help me much because I need the 'line number' and NOT 'row number' when sorted.

The scenario:

I would like to set the focus on one specific row and this focus should remain even after sorting. But if I use the code below, it does not select the correct row.

For example, the index 1 is on the 5th line after sorting. However, the e.item.id still remains as 1, expected is 5.

```
calendar.on("itemClick", function (e) 
{ 
    MyGrid.doclick({ rowIndex: e.item.id }); 
    MyGrid.scrollToRow(e.item.id); 
});
```

Additionally, I also tried...

```
calendar.on("itemClick", function (e)
{
    var identity = MyGrid._by_idx[e.item.id].idty;

    var gridItem = MyGrid.getItem(identity);
    var gridItemIndex = MyGrid.getItemIndex(gridItem);

    MyGrid.doclick({ rowIndex: gridItemIndex });
    MyGrid.scrollToRow(e.item.id);
});
```

Could you please let me know how to get the correct row after fitering? I thank you for your time.

Wishes, 
Santosh

Comment: I am sorry i can't understand what do you mean on sort while you are using calender.on. are you trying toselect a row in a grid based on a a calender filter ?

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response. I have both gridItem and calendarItem. I want to select the right gridItem when I click on the associated calendarItem. Both of them are referred with the Id. So, on calendar Item click, I would like to select the associated row entity.

Comment: I am guessing that the gridItem has the Same Store as the CalnderItem, if yes then i am not sure if the grid item and the calnder item index items in the same way. can you explain your code more or put an example on JSfiddle.

Comment: Hi, thanks for trying to help me. I will give another very small example, where I have similar problem. I have a datagrid, with 2 columns, date and title. When ever a new row is inserted, the rows are sorted with respect to date. I want to highlight the newly created row even after its sorted. the example:     var addRow = function ()
    {
        var newGridItem = new GridItem();
        CreateItem(newGridItem);
        FteGrid.doclick({ rowIndex: newGridItem.Id });
    }; My problem is this newGridItem.Id is different from the row number, as the row number changes after sort

Comment: Okay, I figured out the answer. GetGridItemIndexByGridItem = function (gridItem)
{
    var indexLength = MyGrid._by_idx.length;
    var element = null;
    var gridItemIndex = -1;
    for (var i = 0; i < indexLength; i++)
    {
        element = MyGrid._by_idx[i];
        if (element.item.Guid == gridItem.Guid)
        {
            gridItemIndex = i;
        }
    }
    return gridItemIndex;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured out the answer.

```
GetGridItemIndexByGridItem = function (gridItem) { 
    var indexLength = MyGrid._by_idx.length; 
    var element = null; 
    var gridItemIndex = -1; 

    for (var i = 0; i < indexLength; i++) { 
        element = MyGrid._by_idx[i]; 
        if (element.item.Guid == gridItem.Guid) { 
            gridItemIndex = i; 
        } 
    } 
    return gridItemIndex; 
}
```

Best Wishes